# Scorecard and table discrepancy

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4, looker

Do you have any idea why the numbers on the scorecard and the total in the summary table are different?

Sometimes the discrepancy is quite high.

Thanks for your help.

Amir

Just making dashboard and expecting same data and number.

Comment: Hi Amir, you are going to have to provide a bit more information so that we can help you. examples of the type of data and report you are using would be useful